# Mobile camera sensor specifications (database?)

Tags: sensor, mobile

I already know sites as https://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Camera-Sensor-Database which are good databases for detailed sensors specifications, especially regarding DSLR.

But I would like to find such detailed (i.e. not only the X[Mpx] or the marketing capabilities shown on the main brand website) camera sensors specifications (focal of the lens, pixel size in micron, sensor width and height in mm, technology used for example) for smart-phones or tablets (i.e. any mobile with an embedded camera chip), if possible.

Does such web databases exist for mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this website, resulting from the enormous amount of work by Gregor Brdnik, many many thanks to him:

https://www.digicamdb.com/

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such comprehensive database. Many phone manufacturers *only* provide the marketing information, and even that is often scant. Maintaining such a database would require constantly buying and tearing down phones as they come out. Because the desire for such data is very niche, that is not sustainable.

Comment: Well, some repair advice sites do just that .... :)

Comment: @rackandboneman Generally for popular and high end models only, though.

Comment: Yeah, but many low end smartphones really put the a back in crop sensor anyway....