# How to find sensor width of a phone camera when you only have focal length?

Tags: sensor-size

I have a MotoG6 phone and I need to find out the exact sensor width (trying out photogrammetry, it's pretty cool but Meshroom requires a sensor width, and it'd work a lot better if I didn't have to just guess).

The focal length is 3.95mm. Here's some other possibly usable(...?) information a different (worse) photogrammetry software had as a automatic calibration for the camera:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer ?

Comment: Technically, you can't; There is usually a relationship because the angle of view has to be roughly the same in all cameras but there is enough variation to make the computation imprecise.

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the images? (e.g. 4000x3000, or  4624x2601, etc.)

Comment: I once was searching for some kind of database which gathers the sizes of the different sensors in order to run some batch photogrammetry computation from different sources; https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101912/mobile-camera-sensor-specifications-database
I finally have to search (sometime the information is hard or even impossible to find) on the manufacturers' website or googling with; 'teardown + camera model name'. Hope it can help for future investigations. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

MAIN CAMERA Dual    12 MP, f/1.8, 1/2.55", 1.4µm, PDAF
5 MP, f/2.2, (depth)
Features    Dual-LED dual-tone flash, panorama, auto-HDR
Video   1080p@60/30fps

SELFIE CAMERA   Single  8 MP
or
16 MP, f/2.2, 1/3.1", 1.0µm
Features    LED flash
Video   1080p@30fps

Comment: That 1/2.55" looks like something, could be sensor width but what does the 1/ in front of it mean?

Comment: It means the diagonal of your sensor is 1/2.55 inch. It's simple division. Each Pixel has 1.4 micrometer side length

Comment: @planetmaker That is not correct. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/24954/1943

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for that link